# Unwanted output from switch

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I create a switch that you need to type a number. But I occured a bug which I don't know how to fix it.

```
int user;
void lead() {
    cout << "1 " << flush;
    cin >> user;

    switch (user) {
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    default:
        cout << user << endl;
        lead();
    }
}
```

When I input an alphabet (like "a") it spam the whole console with "1" and "0".
I'm still new to C++ though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not what "alphabet" means!

Comment: You need to clear the invalid input from the stream, and reset its error flags. This is asked very often on SO.

Comment: Don't call lead from inside lead.

Comment: @stark what's so bad about calling a function from within itself? Recursive functions can be very useful in a lot of situations (thinking mainly about a mathematical program)

Comment: @Kvothe Yes recursion when done correctly and for the correct reason is very useful. Instead of a simple loop? Not so much. Especially in this case where the is a big chance of a stack overflow.

Comment: @Kvothe recursion is fine, but that is a horrible reason to recurse. A loop is much more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the input operator `>>` sees the illegal input (it expects decimal integer digits) and then stops, leaving the illegal input in the buffer and also setting `failbit`. That means the next time you attempt to read a value the input operator will see the exact same input as the previous call.

There are a few ways to fix this: One is to read lines of input from the user, and parse it is some way (like e.g. putting the line in a `std::istringstream` and use the normal input operator on that).

Another solution is to tell the input stream (`std::cin` in your case) to [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the rest of the line.

---

On an unrelated note: Don't recursively call the function in the `default` case. Instead use a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But I found out that changing the "int user;" to "string user;" works too.

Comment: @NgYoungShung Yes with a string you could read anything, but if it's supposed to be a number then you have to convert the string yourself later anyway, and *still* have to handle illegal input (and probably using more code as well).